# How exactly Floating Point in stored in Memory in Round Off Cases in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I did my research on floating point calculation and I understood how it is being stored and how inaccuracy comes but with the following case I think its a outlier . Can anyone please help why that it so .

```
Source Code - 
int main()
{        
          float f = 3.9999999f;
          printf("%f",f);
}
```

```
Output - 
4.000000
```

[Question - Why 4.000000 I did calculation  but i am getting around 3.099999976158142089844]

Can anyone please Help me with this .

Compiler spec-
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=somepath\gcc.exe

Target: mingw32
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)

Video I refereed to understand floating point calculation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iV-K-gNDC5A

Comment: "around 3.0999999761" did you mean "around 3.9999999761"? Anyway, the output is rounded (by default) to 6 decimal places.

Comment: Unrelated: the float value is automatically converted to the corresponding value of type `double` for `printf()`... so just go with `double f = 3.99999999;` to begin with :-)

Comment: Start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken...

Comment: I don't understand your question, and the value 3.099... makes no sense, so I assume you mis-typed it.

Comment: Please tell us what you would expect to see instead of 4.000000.

Answer (score 2):

In the format commonly used for `float`, IEEE-754 single precision a.k.a binary32, the two representable values closest to 3.9999999 are 3.9999997615814208984375 and 4. (3.9999997615814208984375 is 16,777,215•2<sup>−22</sup>.)

The distance between 3.9999997615814208984375 and 3.9999999 is about 1.4•10<sup>−7</sup>. The distance between 4 and 3.9999999 is 1•10<sup>−7</sup>. So 4 is closer to 3.9999999 than 3.9999997615814208984375 is. So a C implementation that rounds to the nearest representable value will produce 4 for `3.9999999f`. Thus `float f = 3.9999999f;` initializes `f` to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Befause the difference between 4.000000 and 3.9999999 is less than FLT_EPSILON.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf() */
#include <float.h> /* FLT_EPSILON */

int main(void)
{
    float f;

    /* Prints FLT_EPSILON: 0.00000011920928955078125
       Difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1
       that is representable (for float).

       We can see that 6 zeros after decimal point are
       the default precision of 6 digits for '%f'.

       float can contain up to 23 digits in mantisa. */
    printf("%.23f\n", FLT_EPSILON);

    /* Make something smaller than 4 (anything bigger is 4):
    f = 4 - (FLT_EPSILON + 0.00000000000000000000001) */
    f = 3.99999988079071044921874F;

    /* Prints: 3.99999976158142089843750 == 4 - (FLT_EPSILON + FLT_EPSILON)
       4 - FLT_EPSILON would get rounded to 4. */
    printf("%.23f\n", f);

    /* Prints: 4.000000 */
    printf("%f\n", f);

    return 0;
}
```